# How can I implement Firebase authentication in a Capacitor app on Android and iOS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, capacitor

I'm using Capacitor to create Android and iOS versions of my React webapp and now I'm trying to get firebase authentication working on Android and iOS.

I have allowed navigation inside the app to all domains and am using the `redirect` strategy for Firebase auth.
I have enabled the required authentication methods and they work fine in the web version.

The problem: instead of showing the authentication website, I only get a blank screen.

For reference: the code used for authentication:

```
const auth = firebase.auth()
const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
auth.signInWithRedirect(provider)
```

And the `capacitor.config.json`:

```
{
  "appId": "APP_ID",
  "appName": "APP_NAME",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "yarn",
  "webDir": "build",
  "cordova": {},
  "server": {
    "hostname": "HOSTNAME_KNOWN_TO_FIREBASE",
    "allowNavigation": ["*"]
  },
  "android": {
    "allowMixedContent": true
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Web-based firebase social authentication won't work with the capacitor. It is because the app tries to open the popup or redirect and it fails. In the case of phone authentication, it fails because the window object is not available in the app which is needed for ReCaptcha.

In order to authenticate in the mobile app, you will have to use a capacitor plugin.
[capacitor-firebase-auth](https://github.com/baumblatt/capacitor-firebase-auth#readme)

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are getting an error 400 on your console? Likely you need to enable permissions for your sign-in provider (Google).

To do this, go to Firebase, click on Authentication, then Sign-in method, and change the status of your selected provider to be "Enabled".

[Sign-in Provider Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaTJW.png)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have enabled the authentication methods, so this is not the problem. Will clarify the question

Comment: Has you find a solution to use the web version of firebase in a capacitor App? Thx for answer

Comment: I'm also still searching for a solution